# how to prevent users from directly access a file in a website by using its address

Tags: html, jsp, web, download

I am developing a website(an educational system) in JSP, which has a different users with different accessibility and priority(including teachers, students, managers,...)
Now I want to add some files (e.g. some pdfs) to this website, that only a group of users(e.g. teachers) can download them after logged in to the system. now my Question is how can I prevent others from downloading them by directly typing the file addresses in address bar? In other words I don't want the users to have access to these files directly by typing URLs

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent people from downloading a file by entering its URI. That is simply how the web works. (If you don't want something to be downloaded by anybody, don't put it somewhere that will give it a URI).

However, it sounds like your problem is "Preventing people who are not authorised to download a file from downloading a file", which is a completely different problem.

There are two basic approaches to solving this type of problem.

### Only make the files available through a script

First, don't keep the file under the webroot. Then write a script that:

1. Checks what file the user wants to download (e.g. via a query string parameter)
2. Checks if the user is authenticated
3. Checks if the user is authorized to download the file
4. Identifies the file type and sends a suitable Content-Type header
5. Reads the content of the file and outputs that too

### Configure your web server to perform auth/authz

The specifics of this will depend on the web server software you use. I've no idea if there are any methods to tell any server that supports JSP to perform auth/authz using whatever Java login system you are using, but I have done it using Apache/mod_perl in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Who says you even need to have your PDF available on the URL?

You could have a password protected page, such as `servepdf.jsp` ...that has a check on it to see if a person is logged in or not.

If they're logged in, you could then pass parameters to the page such as `servepdf.jsp?pdf=HGJDF9798734FKJHKHJFSF` (some kind of unique ID stored in a database) that gets the file from a directory **outside** of the web root (where users wouldn't normally be able to get to).

Could that be an option?

Comment: "some kind of unique ID stored in a database"

I disagree with static ID, you should use token instead and generate a different ID every time a user request to download.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to setup a symbolic link and use .htaccess to redirect depending on your preferences.

Comment: would you please explain more?

Comment: This is a useful place to start.  Check out the security section and experiment with some of their options.

http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#security

Comment: The question mentions (and is tagged) JSP. What makes you think that Apache HTTPD is being used?